# Problema con php7 <=> switch

Tags: php, php7

Estoy practicando con las novedades de php7 en comparación con php5 y me encontré con este problema cuando se utiliza el comparador de triple via `<=>` y switch, ya que obtengo un resultado incorrecto cuando imprimo el resultado en pantalla o consola, les dejo el código, espero por favor puedan explicarme el porque de este comportamiento.

```
<?php

$bar = 1;   
$foo = 2;  

switch ($bar <=> $foo) {
case 0:
   echo "\$bar and $foo are equal";
case -1:
   echo "\$foo is bigger";
case 1:
   echo "\$bar is bigger";
 }
 ?>
```

Este es el resultado:

```
$ php numero1.php
$foo is bigger$bar is bigger
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problema**

> Tu estructura de control esta incompleta, por cada `case` posterior a retornar un valor se debe tener un `break`

**Solución**

> Posterior, para cada `case` de tu estructura de control, posterior a que devuelves o retornas un valor debes tener un `break` que rompa o termine la ejecución del código.

**Ejemplo de estructura de control `switch`**

```
$var = 1;

switch($var){
    case 1:
    return "Este valor1";
    break;
    case 2:
    return "Este valor2";
    break;
    case 3:
    return "Este valor3";
    break;
}
```

**Código corregido**

```
<?php

$bar = 1;   
$foo = 2;  

switch ($bar <=> $foo) {
case 0:
   echo "\$bar and $foo are equal";
   break;
case -1:
   echo "\$foo is bigger";
   break;
case 1:
   echo "\$bar is bigger";
   break;
 }
 ?>
```

**Enlace de interés**

- [Estructura de control `switch`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php)